# Can't get to modify a DIV content using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to edit a `DIV` contents using a `document.getElementById` function from an `onclick` action on a button. 
   I have tried all kinds of methods :

```
Element.update(element[, newContent]);
document.getElementByName('myElement').innerHTML='New Text';
document.getElementById('supprimerMatiere').innerHTML='New Text';
document.getElementById('supprimerMatiere').innerText='New Text';
document.getElementById('supprimerMatiere').value='New Text';
```

None of them worked for me. Here's my DIV:

```
<div name="supprimerMatiere" class="alert alert-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Old Text </div>
```

And here's my button, where I want to put the function to edit my DIV text :

```
<button onclick="document.getElementByName('supprimerMatiere').innerHTML='New Text';" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-title="Supprimer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" data-placement="top" rel="tooltip"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
```

Please help, I'm stuck with this for 3 days and didn't find a solution on the internet.

Comment: Try `onclick="document.getElementByName('supprimerMatiere')[0].innerHTML`!

Comment: you don't have an `id` set for your div so `getElementById` won't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName` and it returns an `nodelist`. Say like bellow

```
onclick="document.getElementsByName('supprimerMatiere')[0].innerHTML='New Text';"
```

Answer (score 0):

But the text inside a span, like so:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign">Old Text</span>
```

Then do:

```
$(#supprimerMatiere span).text('New Text')
```

with Jquery.

EDIT: Without Jquery:

```
document.getElementById("yourspanID").innerHTML = "New Text";
```

Comment: maybe user doesnt want to use jQuery library, its not needed here.

Comment: so that your update works, you should at least create id for the span.

Answer (score 0):

there is no such method named `getElementByName(element)`

so its better use id attribute
and use `getElementById`
or `getElementsByName(name)[index]`

here is test [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/ehhyc9x0/)